# How to use pandas where i have to split the Date column and find out the no of days delayed

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the code:

Cell 1:

```
%matplotlib notebook

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

purchase_data = pd.read_csv('Lokad_PurchaseOrders.csv')

purchase_data
```

Cell 2:

```
import datetime
import math
from datetime import date

start_date = purchase_data.Date
end_date = purchase_data.DeliveryDate
def d(s):
  [day, month, year] = map(int, s.split('-'))
  return date(day, month, year)

def delay(end, start):
  return (d(end) - d(start)).days  

delay(end_date, start_date)
```

Here is the error message:

```
AttributeError    
                        Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-19-ce1db3e6387fin <module>()

     13 

     14 

---15 delay(end_date, start_date)


<ipython-input-19-ce1db3e6387fin delay(end, start)

     10 

     11 def delay(end, start):

---12     return (d(end) - d(start)).days

     13 

     14 

<ipython-input-19-ce1db3e6387fin d(s)

      6 end_date = purchase_data.DeliveryDate

      7 def d(s):

----8     [day, month, year] = map(int, s.split('-'))

      9     return date(day, month, year)

     10 

F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
__getattr__(self, name)

   2968             if name in self._info_axis:

   2969                 return self[name]

-2970             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

   2971 

   2972     def __setattr__(self, name, value):


AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should make sure that the `end_date` and `start_date` are both strings rather than Series object as the error says. You can check that using the `type()` function.

And to split the Series type data, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44049442/3552975).

Secondly, I think in this function:

```
def delay(end, start):
  return (d(end) - d(start)).days
```

`(d(end) - d(start))` may don't have the `days` attribute.

May this help.